# Detecting Duplicates Using Divide and Conquer - Merge Sort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I want to detect duplicates in a given array using divide and conquer approach. Can I use Merge Sort for this:

1. First split the array in log N steps
2. Then sort by merging
3. While merging use a counter variable to detect duplicates. O(N)

So in total it will take O(N log N) steps...

Is this approach correct?

Comment: I think your approach is correct if you want to you divide and conquer only to find duplicates. Otherwise as mentioned in answers, use divide and conquer to sort and then find duplicates in O(N). So total time will be O(NlogN)

Comment: @abhinav How will it be O(NlogN)? Lets take--You are performing merge sort in O(NlogN) and then performing another sorting in O(N).. so total time would be O(NlogN)+another O(N) for iteration?

Comment: Wouldn't this add up to O(NLogN)?

Comment: @abhinav Yeah your are right!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use merge sort to sort the array which takes O(nlogn) , once the array is sorted
you can detect duplicates in O(n) time so total time is O(nlogn).

For example the array is `arr[]` and it has `N` elements.

```
1.Sort array using merge sort.

2. (a)variables 
   start -- initially at position 1 of array (arr has elements from 1 to N).
   count--- to count number of times a specific number occurs

   (b)method
   for(i=2;i<=N;i++)
   {
       if(arr[i]!=arr[start])
       { 
           printf("%d has occurred %d times",arr[start],count);
           count=1;
           start=i;
       }
       else count++;
   }
   printf("%d has occurred %d times",arr[start],count);
```

Thuis total time O(nlogn) space O(n).

Comment: This will take more than O(NlogN) I suppose... because you have made merge sort a seperate step which will take O(NlogN) and then used iteration O(N).Sorry I did not mean this.. While merging (combining step in merge sort) and comparisons, we can count the number of iterations knoe?

Comment: @sundar first of all O(nlogn +n) is O(logn) as nlogn dominates n see how both functions grow. Also clear your defination of big 'O'.And yes you can count duplicates while merging. But it will mean the same thing as in merge sort you will detect duplicates in parts of original array and in the method i mentioned you do all at once.Both are one and the same thing. cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to. You can do it in O(n)

You have the original array int A[N]; Create a secound array bool a[N] too, of type bool=false. Iterate the first array and set a[A[i]]=true if was false, else you have found a duplicate.

Comment: Great Thanks... But I want to know whether the divide and conquer paradigm will work or not...

Comment: also this will require additional O(N) space.

Comment: If you are okay to modify the same array this doesn't require additional space. You can store the bool flag in the same array.

Comment: This requires that the input consists of integers and have a limited range, which was not stated in the question. And `a[N]` needs to be `a[K]` where K is the maximum allowed value. And the additional space used is O(K).